# How to compile my Java project using GNU Make?

Tags: java, makefile

I have a Java project with two packages:

- `src`

  - `Main.java`
- `lib`

  - `AVLTree.java`
  - `TreeNode.java`
  - `TreeVisualizer.java`

I want to write a makefile that compiles all the `.java` files to `.class` files and stores them in `bin/lib` and `bin/src` respectively. How can I write a simple `Makefile` to do that?

Commands I'm using right now to do this are:
`javac -d bin lib\* src\*`
(Currently on Windows)

To run, I'm using:
`java -cp bin\ src\Main.java`

Comment: Does it have to be GNU Make? What about [gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [maven](https://maven.apache.org/)?

Comment: It's not a mandatory requirement for my project, I just want to try it using GNU Make for the sake of learning.

Comment: "How to move my Honda car with a team of oxen?" I suggest you focus your attention on more useful ways of compiling and building. Modern Java apps are built with [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s using the compiler bundled with a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (usually named `javac`) invoked by a build management system such as [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or Apache Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Makefile that should do what you want:

```
JC = javac
JFLAGS = -d bin

.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

SRCDIR = src
LIBDIR = lib
BINDIR = bin
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.java)
LIBS = $(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/*.java)
CLASSES = $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.java=$(BINDIR)/%.class) $(LIBS:$(LIBDIR)/%.java=$(BINDIR)/%.class)

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES)

clean:
    $(RM) $(BINDIR)/*.class
```

Comment: It's giving me this error:
`Makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040064/makefile-for-java

Comment: That error means that you indented the recipe line (line 6, and probably also the last line after the `clean:` target) with spaces.  Make requires an actual TAB character to be used.  Be careful that your editor is not replacing TAB characters with spaces, either at input or when you save the file.